# Are there any open source API's to push and pull data tables from SQL to Google Cloud(Big Query) and Vice Versa?

Tags: cloud-storage, sql-server, asp.net, cloud-computing, cloud

Part of my jobs is to push and pull data tables from SQL to the Google cloud (Big Query) and vice versa. I was wondering if there are any robust API's that can be used in my web apps, SSIS Packages, Executable to call and pass the required parameters like table-name, connection string and project name and so on...

Please suggest, thanks.